# Matching optional String regex

Tags: regex

i have to find a solution for my little Problem :-/.

I have a message eg

Status: OK

or

Status: ERR|next Message

is it possible to create a regex for "Status" + optional the Message if exists ?

Thanks a lot

Rene

Comment: What is the expression for? Do you want to extract the status code?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? http://regular-expressions.info is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
/^Status:\s*([A-Z]+)(?:\|([^$]*))?$/
```

This matches all the data, and returns OK or ERR as the first element, and only the message as the second element.

**Additional information**: The `(?:` notation (before the \|), is a "hidden" grouping. That is, group but don't fetch.

Comment: Whoa, a capturing group inside a non-capturing group? Nice :P

Comment: Thanks. It can be a powerful tool :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/Status: (\w+)(\|(.+))?/
```

This will capture the status code (OK, ERR) in the first group, and a message (if present in the string) in the third group.

Comment: but is it posible without the "|" ?

Comment: The `\|` in the regex is used to match the "|" that separates the status code and the message in the strings you gave. Do you mean that the strings won't actually contain "|" characters?

Comment: I need the Status Message without the | :-)